# Hibernate 5 + Spring + JDBC thin client UCP interfaces not visible to classloader

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, osgi, classloader

I have upgraded the following libraries:

- Spring 3.2.0 -> 4.3.22
- Hibernate 4.1.1 -> 5.1.11

Of note I also use JDBC thin client libraries

- OJDBC 7
- ucp 12.1.0
- ons 12.1.0

I am working on an Axis2 service that ends is deployed in a WSO2 Application Server. Part of the initialization is to load the hibernate session factory. The definition is as follows.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

When I go to initialize the bean, I do it through a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext pointing towards the file with my hibernate session factory definition.

```
final ClassLoader classLoader = service.getClassLoader();
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"repository/conf/pda/applicationContext_dataInventory.xml"}, false)
appCtx.setClassLoader(classLoader);
appCtx.refresh(); // <--- Causes error
```

When I call `appCtx.refresh()`, I receive an exception stating

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface oracle.ucp.jdbc.LabelableConnection is not visible from class loader
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:616)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:592)
        at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:244)
        at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:141)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:455)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:738)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.ConnectionProxyFactory.createConnectionProxy(ConnectionProxyFactory.java:79)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1046)
        at com.xxx.espds.cim.dataMgmt.hibernate.FailoverPoolDataSource.getConnection(FailoverPoolDataSource.java:519)
        at com.xxx.espds.cim.dataMgmt.hibernate.FailoverPoolDataSource.getConnection(FailoverPoolDataSource.java:497)
        at com.xxx.espds.cim.dataMgmt.hibernate.FailoverPoolDataSource.getConnection(FailoverPoolDataSource.java:492)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$3.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:677)
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:471)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:422)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:711)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:727)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1689)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
```

If I manually load the class before the refresh call by calling `appCtx.getClassLoader().loadClass("oracle.ucp.jdbc.LabelableConnection");` then this specific error will go away, but I will just end up having an error on another interface not being visible to the classloader. My thoughts are that is has something to do with Spring/Hibernate not using the same classLoader as I have given to the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.

Why are the UCP classes not visible at the time of session factory initialization?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by setting the threads classloader to the ClassLoader used for the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. The oracle JDBC eventually attempts to load some of its own classes from the UCP dependency using the `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();`. The code that illustrates the fix is detailed below

```
// Get current thread ClassLoader and reset it after we do the initial load. While we previously set the
// Spring ClassLoader, when we initialize the UCP ConnectionPool via the hibernate sessionFactory the jdbc
// thin client attempts to load classes using the currentThread().getContextClassLoader(). To get around this,
// we need to set the threads ClassLoader to the one that has information on the JDBC libraries, and since we
// always package up the libraries in each service, that would be the service.getClassLoader()
final ClassLoader classLoader = service.getClassLoader();
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"applicationContext.xml"}, false);
appCtx.setClassLoader(classLoader);
ClassLoader threadLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
appCtx.refresh();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(threadLoader);
```